# how to remove the ICU4J library from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, icu4j

After creating an Android Studio project, the ICU4J library will be added to the project Automatically.it increases the APK file size to 15 MB.
I do not use this library, but I can not delete it.

You can see inside the APK Analyzer too:
[image: APK Analyzer for ICU4J library]

How to remove the ICU4J library from the project

Comment: check you gradle

Comment: can you post snippet of your grade dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Gradle file dependencies if there is dependency to icu4j remove it or  if you are not using icu4j you can add

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

in your build configurations to remove unused code from your application.

or You can find [shrinking code and resources documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Comment: There is no in dependencies

Comment: minifyEnabled true Not Work :(

Comment: @sajjadYosefi Dear Friend than you might be using icu4j in your code, Try to  use find in code facility of android studio (shift + ctrl + f) OR (shift + cmd + f) to find icu4j in your code.

Comment: I chek it by (shift + ctrl + f) too

Answer (score 0):

Go to **App Gradle**. Here you can find the all libraries using on your project.

Remove the compile code of ICU4J library from dependencies

```
dependencies {
    //Remove the unwanted libraries / dependencies 
}
```

Comment: There is no in dependencies

Comment: in External Libraries but can not remove it